# Can't Disable Vim Mode in Sublime Text Even After Editing Settings

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm unable to disable the Vim mode in Sublime Text.

Despite adding `"Vintage"` to the `ignored_packages` list in my settings like this(This will disable the Vim mode.):

```json
"ignored_packages": ["Vintage"],
```

each time I close and reopen Sublime Text, it automatically reverts to:

```json
"ignored_packages": [],
```

I am using Windows and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Sublime Text several times, but the issue persists. Does anyone know how to permanently disable Vim mode in Sublime Text on Windows?

Comment: What other packages do you have installed? The default `ignored_packges` setting includes `Vintage`, and the core does not ever remove items from it, only an external force can do that

Comment: Ah, right. It seems that the issue doesn't occur anymore after I disabled all plugins. Maybe it's a problem caused by the plugins. This issue started happening in the past few months, possibly due to the plugins being updated.